# GridLayout frustrations

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridlayout

I have a series of controls that I need to layout in a 3x2 grid (limited to only 6 controls visible at a time). I need to be able to change a cell's visibility to gone and have the next visible control in the list align itself on the previous column or row depending on where it already sits. I also need to force each cell into a perfect square, but make the width of each cell half the screen size. Is there a way I can make this happen in XML without having to resort to using an adapter in java?

Comment: no. there's no way you can implement this in XML. You'll have to use Java.

Comment: *facepalm* Android seriously needs to learn that sometimes we need to maintain aspect ratios....

Comment: I don't see it as a facepalm, XML is a static layout. With all the constraints you setup, you need a very dynamic approach to layouting, there's where Java comes in.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that I've gotten every piece of this to work *except* that it doesn't maintain the aspect ratio of the cells. That is something that android should make simple, and everyone else seems to make simple, where all you would have to do is check the width and apply it to the height.

Comment: you can do easily with a custom view. just override `onMeasure`. Search for "android square view"

Comment: Yea, I know. But my question was mainly whether I can avoid  that.

Comment: You should provide a image of what you want.